# Android bug ao executar projeto em emulador

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou tentando executar um projeto no Android Studio e esta dando um erro que não sei como resolver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gradle Console:

```
> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources,
> :app:generateDebugTestSources]
> 
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild
> :app:preDebugBuild :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugTestBuild :app:prepareDebugTestDependencies
> :app:compileDebugTestAidl UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugTestManifest
> UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugTestAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugTestAssets
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> :app:mergeDebugTestResources UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugTestResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugTestSources UP-TO-DATE
> 
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
> 
> Total time: 4.634 secs Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
> 
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild
> :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild
> :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJava 


> An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0_71). Please file a bug at the Java Developer
> Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the
> Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following
> diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
> com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
> bolts.Task not found
> 
>  FAILED
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> 
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> 
> BUILD FAILED
> 
> Total time: 4.084 secs
```

Comment: Sem o log de erros fica praticamente impossível detectar o problema.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro seria isso?

Comment: Não é isso. Vá em `View > Gradle Console` e cole o texto do log na sua pergunta. Fica melhor pra visualizar do que em um screenshot.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro não tem esta opção.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro finalmente encontrei, vou atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Qualquer projeto causa o Crash ou é um projeto especifico?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento só tenho este na máquina por enquanto, sou iniciante em Android.

Comment: Mas você tentou criar um projeto do "zero" sem nada e compilar? Por que antes de tudo precisamos definir se o problema é na instalação do AndroidStudio ou no seu projeto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acabei de fazer o teste, funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Então o problema é com o outro projeto e não com o AndroidStudio, portanto imagens ou `Gradle Console` não vão ajudar muito. O que você deve fazer é postar o código seguindo estas especificações: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `class file for bolts.Task not found`. Esse parece ser o seu problema. É provável que alguma biblioteca tenha como dependência o Bolts framework, mas o jar não foi incluído no projeto.